# How to render values received from REDUX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this simple example page test in ReactJS:

[image]

On change the new value of the select is sent to the STORE (REDUX).

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SelecionarCrypto from "./SelecionarCrypto";

  class PruebasAPI4 extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

    }

    render() {

      return (
        <Fragment>
          Test4
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <SelecionarCrypto />
          <br></br>

          Value of select (Typeof): {typeof this.props.selectvalue}
        <br></br>
        Value of select (props): {this.props.selectvalue}
        {console.log("Test inside retun value of this.props ",this.props )}
        <br></br>

        </Fragment>

    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("mapStateToProps receives: ", state)
  return {
    token: state.token,
    ValorState: state.ValorState,
    username: state.username,
    selectvalue: state.value  // <<<---- This one 

  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PruebasAPI4);
```

The value selected is received correctly inside the mapStateToProps

[image]

The page is not rendering when receiving new value from store and the value is always undefined.

[image]

How to map the received value and each time a change ocure render to see the value on the page??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your code. It should be:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    ...
    selectvalue: state.selectvalue  // Instead of state.value

  };
};
```